# How to pass Powershell variable value into a cmd prompt

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

In powershell, I need to pass a variable into a command in cmd prompt. 
It would take this structure, and yes I need to open command prompt.

```
Variable= 5 points
$prog="cmd.exe"  ''open cmd
$params=@("/C")
```

But I'm confused about the third line- can someone demonstrate for me an example of passing a variable in that line with some other parameters?

Comment: why you need to pass a var to cmd ? any thing that you can do in cmd you can also do in powershell

Answer (score 3):

Just list **string** variables (a sample without `@()` syntax):

```
$prog = "cmd.exe"
$path = "C:\Users\user\Documents"
$params = "/C", "dir", $path

& $prog $params
```

---

This will work fine too:

```
$args = "dir", "C:\Users\user\Documents"
& cmd /c $args
```